# three-level directory list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a one liner replacement for my current implementation?

```
Top Level
-- Sub Level
--- Folder
-- Sub Level
--- Folder
.
.
.
```

To get the `-- Folder` in each `-- Sub Level` I have the following:

```
dir_ = '/path/to/Top Level'
sub_lvl = [os.path.join(dir_, sub) for sub in os.listdir(dir_)]
# "folder" is always a fixed name
folders = [os.path.join(sub, "folder") for sub in sub_lvl]
```

Comment: how about simply replacing the `sub_lvl` in the lower list-comprehension with its value from two lines above?

Comment: `folders = [os.path.join(os.path.join(dir_, sub), "folder") for sub in os.listdir(dir_)]  ` should work.

Comment: @MarvinTaschenberger Post as solution. Worked beautifully. As for need for a one liner, just more pythonic and cleaner imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go :

```
folders = [os.path.join(os.path.join(dir_, sub), "folder") for sub in os.listdir(dir_)]
```

Comment: This assumes there are only folders inside `dir_`.

Comment: @LUB It _assumes_ but that's how it is implemented. See my post above and youll see that under `Top Level` are `Sub Level` elements; no files just directories. So implementation makes this worthy!

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join` takes an arbitrary number of strings. And you should check if the item is a folder:

```
sub_lvl = [os.path.join(dir_, sub, "folder") for sub in os.listdir(dir_) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_,sub))]
```